# what are the rules regarding $x,a,b$ for this expression to be true: $(x^a)^b = (x^b)^a$ (i am considering only for when $a,b$ are real)?

Tags: radicals

in particular i am asking for the case when one of the powers $a$ or $b$ is a fraction.  in such a case, i believe the maths expression then may be ambiguous, as when you do to the power of a fraction, it's not clear if the required answer is the principal root, or if it is all roots.

eg i know $(4^{\frac12})^2 = 4$
but is $(4^2)^{\frac12} = 4$?  in this case, i think it's ambiguous, some will say also $-4$ is a solution , so we should add some notation that we want the "principal root" , and then it is true

Comment: $\sqrt{4^2}\ne-4$

Answer (score 0):

If $n\in\Bbb N$, and $x\geqslant0$, $x^{1/n}$ is the only number $y\geqslant0$ such that $y^n=x$ . In particular, $(4^2)^{1/2}=16^{1/2}=4$.

And, if $x>0$, and $a,b\in\Bbb R$, $\left(x^a\right)^b=\left(x^b\right)^a$. Actually, both numbers are equal to $x^{ab}$. To see why, I will assume that you define $x^a$ as $e^{a\log x}$. Then\begin{align}\left( x^a\right)^b&=e^{b\log\left(x^a\right)}\\&=e^{ab\log x}\\&=x^{ab}.\end{align}

Comment: and what if x<0 ?

Comment: Then $x^a$ is undefined, in general. For instance, what would be $(-3)^{1/4}$?

Comment: no, i dont think it is undefined, the outcome contains an imaginary component

Comment: Then teach me. What's the definition?

Comment: (-3)^(1/4) = ((-3)^(1/2))^1/2).   (-3)^(1/2) = (-1)^0.5 * 3^0.5 = J.SQRT(3).   so (-3)^0.25 = SQRT(J) . 4TH ROOT OF 3   , where j = i = sqrt(-1)

Comment: My question was: what's the definition of $x^a$ when $x<0$. And, by the way, where did you find it?